# Cart Price Rules always applied - regardles of storeview, status or even expiry date

Tags: magento2, error, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I have a problem with Magento 2 (2.4.3-p1) where the Cart Price Rules are always applied to products on the checkout. Regardless of the rule is active, conditions are met, the coupon code was entered or not or even the store view the rule is assigned.

The only way to get rid of discounts is to remove all Card Price Rules from the Magento Admin page. This behaviour only affects frontend checkouts.

Could someone help how to investigate what can cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't set a condition for the rule. You can add conditions so that the rule only applies to a specific category or product

Step 1. Log in to your Admin panel and navigate to Marketing > Promotions > Cart Price Rule.

Step 2. Click on the Add New Rule button. On the opened page, you need to fill in 4 blocks: Rule Information, Conditions, Actions, and Label.

Step 3. In the Rule Information tab, set the Name, activate the rule, assign the rule to the Website, and choose the Customer Group that can use it.

Step 4. In the Condition tab, you can configure specific product attribute combinations